# SQL Using multiple AND & OR in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

Having a problem getting correct results from my Query.

My main issue is that I have a column called filterlist which contains data in this format `[space]NUMBER[space]`

```
 | 2 | 16 | 7 |
```

I need to select all products that match my first query using this Where statement -

```
WHERE     
    (dept = '5') AND (active = 1) AND (Manufacturer = 'A Company')
```

Then I need to add to this the following to find records where the column  `filterlist` contains any of the String values `[space]NUMBER[space]` using -

```
(CHARINDEX(' 2 ', filterlist) > 0) OR (CHARINDEX(' 3 ', filterlist) > 0) 
OR (CHARINDEX(' 64 ', filterlist) > 0)
```

The full SQL I have tried with is

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE 
    ((dept = '5') AND (active = 1) AND (Manufacturer = 'A Company')) 
    AND ((CHARINDEX(' 3 ', filterlist) > 0) OR 
         (CHARINDEX(' 34 ', filterlist) > 0) OR 
         (CHARINDEX(' 64 ', filterlist) > 0))
```

So I'm looking to get all records that have dept as 5, is active, made by 'A Company' and that the column filterlist contains either 3,34 or 64 (as an example)

**UPDATE:** it all works fine with this part:

```
WHERE 
((dept = '5') AND (active = 1) AND (Manufacturer = 'A Company')) 
AND ((CHARINDEX(' 3 ', filterlist) > 0)
```

but pulls in other records from the wrong Dept/Manufacturer when this section is added

```
 OR 
     (CHARINDEX(' 34 ', filterlist) > 0) OR 
     (CHARINDEX(' 64 ', filterlist) > 0))
```

I would be very grateful if anybody could point me in the direction of how this can be done.

Comment: The code looks okay to me.  I'm curious to verify the data.  Are you able to set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example provide the table struct and a record or two?

Comment: never used this before but will look at setting up sqlfiddle account now

Comment: have set up sqlfiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/109814/1

Comment: Phil, the SQLFiddle seems to work like @user212514 mentioned. I believe you would have had one of the closing braces in the incorrect place when you ran the query first, causing the OR conditions to move outside the scope of the manufacturer condition in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you consider to keep numeric fields in numeric types?
2. if not possible then you can use this

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM products 
   WHERE ((dept = '5') AND (active = 1) AND (Manufacturer = 'A Company')) 
    AND ltrim(rtrim(filterlist)) in ('3','34','64')
   ```

Comment: Produced no results, dont need to get rid of spaces just need to search using each row with CHARINDEX for the presence of the strs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for creating the SQLFiddle.  This query returns the two rows that are have 'A Company' so I think it is correct (I removed `dept` because it wasn't in `products`, but that doesn't make a difference in this example because we still have the same logical combinations, just one fewer).

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE 
    ((active = 1) AND (Manufacturer = 'A Company')) 
    AND ((CHARINDEX(' 3 ', filterlist) > 0) OR 
         (CHARINDEX(' 34 ', filterlist) > 0) OR 
         (CHARINDEX(' 64 ', filterlist) > 0))
```

Additionally when I changed to `Manufacturer = 'B Company'` I got only the third record.

It makes sense to me...Am I missing something?